# Some keys don't work

Tags: 16.04, updates, keyboard-layout, .desktop

So I'm new to ubuntu and I just updated to 16.04 software and when I type my username, password and I've read to type the command "startx" to get to my desktop but insted of the "x" key (also y,q,w) on screen appears little dot or rhombus 
And also, some keys which, since my keyboard is on us layout I wasn't previously able to type in like: š,ž,ć suddenly now I can
Also, pressing "ctrl+alt+F1-12 does absolutely nothing
How can I get to my desktop?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Yeah I did but then the screen just goes blank

Comment: How are you typing your user name and password? In GUI or on command line?

Comment: In command line

Comment: How did you install/update? I hope you did not install just for the command line.

Comment: Well it asked if I want to and I clicked yes. Now after it's upgraded and restarted says: "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (my name) tty1" and "(my name) login:" Sorry if I'm confusing you but as I said I'm new to all this and don't really know what I'm suposed to do

Comment: Try installing it again maybe?

Answer (score 0):

When on the login screen you can click the keyboard layout indicator (one of the icons at the top right). Hopefully it gives you the opportunity to switch to the desired layout.